# CVE-2022-42889 in Apache Commons Text and impact on Cassandra 3.11.x

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, apache-commons-text

Can someone help and share information, is there any analysis available to know which Cassandra 3.11.x version is not impacted directly or indirectly by CVE-2022-42889?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. I have cast a vote to have your post moved to dba.stackexchange.com instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.11.13 definitely is not affected by CVE-2022-42889. Have scanned using Grype, Trivy and XRay. It is not appearing in scan result.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Cassandra does not use Apache Commons Text so is not affected by the vulnerability reported in [CVE-2022-42889](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-42889) but I'm happy to be corrected if someone has additional information.

For future reference, you should provide background information on why you think a vulnerability applies to a software. You need to specifically provide:

- evidence that shows why it applies
- details of the analysis you have performed

If you are able to show that you have done some research before asking, others are more likely to help. Cheers!